# Azure DevOps -- using Docker-Compose task to deploy to Azure Container Instances

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, docker-compose, azure-container-instances

I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline for a multi-container solution implemented via docker-compose.yml. The goal is to run a container group in Azure Container Instances.

I went with this task [DockerCompose@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-compose-v0?view=azure-pipelines) for the release pipeline, and the steps to build containers and to deploy them to Azure Container Registry are straighforward.

But, I cannot figure out if it's possible to configure this task to deploy and run containers in ACI. There is an option to Run the Images, but the images are run on the agent's docker host:

[image]

How do I instruct this task that the containers to be run in ACI? I know there is a way to do that via Docker CLI with a step to connect to the ACI context, but I can't figure out how to switch to the ACI context from the DevOps pipeline.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out yet? I am also running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

How do I instruct this task that the containers to be run in ACI?

Ans:
The new release pipeline needs to start with an empty job and provide a name for the release definition. Next, we need to add artefacts to our application. Since all we want to deploy is a Docker image located in the ACR, select the artefact type as the Azure Container Registry (ACR).

Here is the blog [tutorial](https://mohitgoyal.co/2018/11/01/configure-ci-cd-for-azure-container-instances-using-azure-azure-devops-pipelines/) to Configure CI/CD for Azure Container Instances using Azure / Azure DevOps Pipelines given by @mohitgoyal.